# Realtime аналог Firebase для собственного сервера

Tags: база-данных

Требуется документоориентированная база данных, которая будет работать на собственном сервере (не в чьем-то облаке), по функционалу похожая на `Google Firebase`. Я бы, лично, с радостью использовал последнюю, но стоит условие, что находиться она должна у нас и должна работать под `Android`, имея при этом слушатели на изменения в базе для обновления данных в реальном времени.

Пробовал использовать `CouchBase` в связке с `CouchBase Lite` через Sync Gateway. Потратил уйму времени, но не смог завести хоть какой-нибудь рабочий экземпляр. Да и удобства в ней мало. Документация у нее оставляет желать лучшего, постоянно натыкался на уже устаревшие примеры и методы. Когда пытался подключить ее, думал только о том, насколько у Google в этом плане все в разы лучше. Конечно, сначала я пробовал искать в сети аналоги, но там только аналогичные облачные решения.

Возможно, есть что-то, подходящее под условия.

Comment: посмотрите тут https://hashnode.com/post/best-alternatives-for-firebase-ciibz8dtz0069j3xtdvdyf7sl